# Donsker's Invariance for independent, identical mean, variance random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems

Is there an extension of standard Donsker's Invariance Principle to a sequence of independent random variables with zero mean and unit variance but not necessarily identically distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Repeat?
[Is there an extension of Donsker's invariance principle for not identically distributed random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313456/is-there-an-extension-of-donskers-invariance-principle-for-not-identically-dist)

You want convergence to hold on $C[0,1]$, so you might look into general CLTs. They have different ways of going about writing sufficient conditions, but it always comes down to a) something called tightness, which is about concentrating on compact sets and b) convergence at each point in $[0,1]$. The former will follow if your scaled partial sums are uniformly bounded in probability, and the latter will be easy from an i.n.i.d. CLT like Lindeberg-Feller.

Triangular arrays more than take care of non-identical RVs.

Here are some general CLTs

Andersen, Gine, Zinn (allows for infinite variance also): https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-308-02/S0002-9947-1988-0930076-3/S0002-9947-1988-0930076-3.pdf

Araujo, Gine: https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Central_Limit_Theorem_for_Real_and_B.html?id=3exhnQAACAAJ

Comment: Is there any reference on generalization to $C[0, \infty)$?

Comment: I would recommend the Andersen, et. al paper above. It gives almost necessary conditions for CLT, uniform over a general index set, including $[0,\infty)$. This was my main reference for my dissertation, so I may have bias.

If you want other resources, I don't have university access any more. I recommend looking for papers around 1980 by Gine, Arcones, de Acosta.

Here's survey by Gine: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0090613

Also, David Pollard wrote many accessible works if you happen to come across him.

Comment: Are you sure you want uniform convergence, or maybe just compact convergence (uniform on compact sets)?